# Pandas Truncating Column Values Without Rounding

Tags: python, pandas

My input dataframe;

```
A      B
1      1.34934843904358403583408530
3      2.348430840938534058049385340983098
4      1.2309309340949084908908093947
7      15.323927236782
3      102.243984786372541562121652
```

I want to truncate B column with eight digits after dot without rounding, but truncated values should be my new values,not for showing. First values should not stored in the framework's background. And also, B column should be numeric.

Desired output is;

```
A      B
1      1.34934843
3      2.34843084
4      1.23093093
7      15.32392723
3      102.24398478
```

Could you please help me about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea is multiple value by `10**N` value, convert to int and then divide:

```
N = 8
df['B'] = df['B'].mul(10**N).astype(np.int64).div(10**N)
print (df)
   A           B
0  1    1.349348
1  3    2.348431
2  4    1.230931
3  7   15.323927
4  3  102.243985
```

Another idea is convert values to strings with precision and then to floats:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].map(lambda x: "{:.8f}".format(x)).astype(float)
```

Comment: it' s not working on my actual dataframe although i used pd.to_numeric before

Comment: in my data, the values are as follows after running the code; 0.642857140000000049084860620496328920125961303...

Comment: possible, but will I be able to convert it back to float in the last case?

Comment: is it possible any way like truncate function etc.?

Comment: I got an error: ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

Comment: if you have any other suggestions, I will be very grateful.

Comment: @Salih - Special for you - forst strings columns - `df['B'] = df['B'].map(lambda x: x[:x.find('.') + 9]).astype(float)` - if need strings, remove last `.astype(float)`

Comment: When the column is string, it is eight digits so working, but it increases again when it is converted to float type.

Comment: @Salih - Unfortunately it is problem of precision in programming in any language, so still there is problem with any solution. If need floats with many values maybe exist some solution with `Decimal`, but then you cannot working like numbers, because get objects :( So sorry.

Comment: @Salih - Check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)