# How to find number of decimal places in a number also counting trailing zero in python

Tags: python, pandas

My question pertains to counting the number of digits after decimal point using python or pandas. Questions answered so far first convert float to string and then count the number of characters after decimal point. In converting decimal to str(), the trailing zero is lost. But in my case I need to count total number of digits after decimal point including trailing zero, if it exists. That is, for the number 7.80, the answer should be two digits after decimal point and not one digit and, of course, for 7.8, it would be 1 digit after decimal. Please let me know if this is possible.

Actually my problem is this:
Suppose I have a pandas Series something as follows:

```
0.123
0.124
0.123
0.349
0.349
0.340
```

I want to generate two features. One simple value_counts() of existing data.
So answer will be:

```
0.123   2
0.124   1
0.123   2
0.349   2
0.349   2
0.340   1
```

Another feature generation will be value_counts() after removing the last digit. New features will be:

```
0.123   3
0.124   3
0.123   3
0.349   3
0.349   3
0.340   3
```

Thanks for the trouble

Comment: What is the data type of your input? If it's float, the trailing 0 is already lost! `float(7.80)` outputs '7.8'

Comment: Pandas dataframe only of numeric columns

Comment: Please add a chunk of your dataframe and the output for `df.column.describe()`

Comment: Using `decimal` instead of `float` will preserve trailing zeroes when converting to a string.

Comment: In pandas series, astype('decimal') does not work

Answer (score 2):

Working with floats is not always easy, because [`precision`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Here possible solution is multiple values by `100` and convert to integers, and then possible use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for get size of new Series:

```
df['a'] = df['col'].map(df['col'].value_counts())
#alternative
#df['a'] = df.groupby('col')['col'].transform('size')

N = 2
s = df['col'].mul(10 ** N).astype(np.int64)
df['b'] = s.groupby(s).transform('size')
print (df)
     col  a  b
0  0.123  2  3
1  0.124  1  3
2  0.123  2  3
3  0.349  2  3
4  0.349  2  3
5  0.340  1  3
```

Like mentioned @Fourier, you can use if possible (the best test with real data, maybe sometimes failed because float accuracy):

```
N = 2
df['b'] = df['col'].round(N).groupby(df['col']).transform('size')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually I want to make a general function for all columns of data frame where number of decimal digits after decimal may vary. In some columns there may be two and in some columns 5 and so on. In your solution, I will have to supply value to N manually. Is it possible to deduce that automatically.

Comment: Couldn't one get a way with `df.groupby(df['col'].apply(lambda x: round(x, 2))).transform("size")` ?

Comment: And this is the reason for my original question. Just remove the last digit and perform value_counts().

Comment: @user3282777 - hmmm, if string represenation of flots, then possible, but if floats, then problem with real data - `0.1230000005441144` remove last `4` :(

Comment: My data is all numeric columns. Such techniques of feature generation for numerical data have been recommended. Reference slide 30 [here](https://www.slideshare.net/HJvanVeen/feature-engineering-72376750).

Comment: @user3282777 - In my opinion it depends if need round by 2,3, numeric values next `.` then `round` function working perfectly. But if want more values, then round should failed, because float accuracy. So there are integers if need numeric values. Maybe also help my answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710817/pandas-truncating-column-values-without-rounding/58710878#58710878)